# Quantum Automata books

Tags: book-recommendation, automata

I am searching for books that introduce the quantum automata theory, and if it’s possible, with the definitions of *Measure once 1-way quantum finite automata* and *Measure many 1-way quantum finite automata*.

Are there books mainly followed in this kind of courses? Like a Rudin for the Analysis courses.